# Flask not recognizing my custom style sheet

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2, flask-bootstrap

I am rendering a template that I am attempting to style with a custom style sheet. The file structure is as follows:

```
/app
    - __init__.py
    /templates
        - markets.html
        - base.html
    /static
        - custom.css
```

markets.html looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="front-page">

        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col-5">Runeberg</div>
        <div class="col">  </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html looks like this:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

{% block styles %}
    {{ super() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='custom.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
```

And finally, custom.css looks like this:

```
.front-page {
  margin-top: 25%;
}
```

I wrote this code by following [this example here](https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/blob/master/sample_app/templates/base.html). The problem is, the style (front-page) is not being applied.

Answer (score 0):

You are not linking to the css in your html file correctly? Does it work when hardlinking it?

Comment: Hardlinking it did not work. One thing I did notice was when I checked the source using Chrome's dev tools, custom.css shows up as empty (seen here: https://i.imgur.com/rnTytho.png).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263096/css-file-is-not-refreshing-in-my-browser). Chrome's cache didn't reflect the new CSS changes, a hard refresh (shift + f5) did the trick.