# why external css is not working whereas internal css is working fine

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have some code in my external css file which is working perfectly fine. But now when i update my css code in that external css file the update is not working/showing. And if I add that new updated code as internal css than it starts working fine. Can anybody tell what's the reason behind it ?

This is my code in head tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Newsreader:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What did you change? Is this probably a problem of a cached stylesheet file?

Comment: Maybe just a caching issue, you can "force refresh" by long-pressing the refresh button in chrome, if you're in development mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS file not refreshing in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263096/css-file-not-refreshing-in-browser)

Comment: There might be 2 issues 1) The file is cached. Hard reload will fix that. Do a F12 and check the developer window to see if you see your correct css or do you see load errors 2) Check if anything from your custom css gets loaded at all. might be a path issue. ( the server is not able to get to that css)

Comment: So my problem was solved by doing hard reload / force refresh by pressing ctrl+F5